# Checking user input using isnan function of NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, input, python-2.x, notimplementedexception

I'm trying to use NumPy to check if user input is numerical. I've tried using:

```
import numpy as np

a = input("\n\nInsert A: ")

if np.isnan(a):
    print 'Not a number...'
else:
    print "Yep,that's a number"
```

On its own t works fine, however when I embed it into a function such as in this case:

```
import numpy as np

def test_this(a):   
    if np.isnan(a):
        print '\n\nThis is not an accepted type of input for A\n\n'
        raise ValueError
    else:
        print "Yep,that's a number"

a = input("\n\nInsert A: ")

test_this(a)
```

Then I get a `NotImplementationError` saying it isn't implemented for this type, can anyone explain how this is not working?

Comment: 1. avoid `from numpy import *`, you could `import numpy as np` and later use `np.isnan()`, etc instead. 2. Don't compare with `True` directly use `if np.isnan(a)` instead. 3. `input()` does `eval(raw_input(prompt))` it's most probably not what you want.

Answer (score 11):

"Not a Number" or "NaN" is a special kind of floating point value according to the IEEE-754 standard.  The functions `numpy.isnan()` and `math.isnan()` test if a given floating point number has this special value (or one of several "NaN" values).  Passing anything else than a floating point number to one of these function results in a `TypeError`.

To do the kind of input checking you would like to do, you shouldn't use `input()`. Instead, use `raw_input()`,`try:` to convert the returned string to a `float`, and handle the error if this fails.

Example:

```
def input_float(prompt):
    while True:
        s = raw_input(prompt)
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            print "Please enter a valid floating point number."
```

As @J.F. Sebastian pointed out,

> `input()` does `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, it's most probably not what you want.

Or to be more explicit, `raw_input` passes along a string, which once sent to `eval` will be evaluated and treated as though it were command with the value of the input rather than the input string itself.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most encompassing ways of checking if a user input is a valid number in Python is trying to convert it to a float value, and catch the exception.

As denoted in the comments and other answers, the check for NaN has nothing to do with valid user numeric input - rather, it checks if a numeric object has the special value of Not a Number.

```
def check_if_numeric(a):
   try:
       float(a)
   except ValueError:
       return False
   return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = raw_input("\n\nInsert A: ")

try: f = float(a)
except ValueError:
     print "%r is not a number" % (a,)
else:
     print "%r is a number" % (a,)
```