# Error while converting excel date in Python - if np.isnan(date): TypeError: Not implemented for this type

Tags: python, excel, date

I am new to Python coding. I am reading date values from excel to calculate some columns to make an indicator and I am getting this below error :
`if np.isnan(date): TypeError: Not implemented for this type`

Here is the code to convert date value from excel:

**Convert date to string**

```
def return_str_from_excel_date( date ):

if np.isnan(date):
    return ""
else:
    return str(xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(date, 0).timetuple()[2]) + "/" + str(xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(date, 0).timetuple()[1]) + "/" + str(xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(date, 0).timetuple()[0])

elmt_df4['Closing_date_str']     = elmt_df4['Closing date'].apply(lambda date : return_str_from_excel_date(date) )
elmt_df4['Due_date_str']     = elmt_df4['Due_date'].apply(lambda date : 
return_str_from_excel_date(date) )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507509/checking-user-input-using-isnan-function-of-numpy#:~:text=%22Not%20a%20Number%22%20or%20%22NaN%22%20is%20a%20special,one%20of%20these%20function%20results%20in%20a%20TypeError.

Comment: Modified few words in the body & title to make it easier to understand the context of the question !